# Is it possible to change specific cursor on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: gnome, 18.04, cursor

There is already many ways to change the cursor's theme on Ubuntu, Tweak for example, but I need to change a specific cursor to another shape. Indeed, I want to change the I-bean cursor to another one.

Comment: A couple of old links: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=623865 , http://shallowsky.com/linux/x-cursor-themes.html